# No Puedo hacer funcionar el crud de laravel con Vue ERROR 500

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

ayer empeze a usar vue en Laravel.
hice el CRUD y el (Create) no tiene ningún problema, pero a la hora de querer editar o borrar no funciona.

este es el codigo:

```
methods: {
        onClickDelete(){
            axios.delete('/pensamientos/${this.pensamiento.id}').then(()=>{
                this.$emit('delete');
            });
        },
        onClickEdit(){
            this.editMode = true;
        },
        onClickUpdate(){
            const params = {
                descripcion: this.pensamiento.descripcion
            }
            axios.put('/pensamientos/${this.pensamiento.id}', params).then((response) => {
                this.editMode = false;
                const pensamiento = response.data;
                this.$emit('update', this.pensamiento);
            });

        }
    }
```

el input y los botones de donde se obtienen los resultados

```
<div class="card-body">
        <input v-if="editMode" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="pensamiento.descripcion">
        <p v-else> {{ pensamiento.descripcion }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
        <button v-if="editMode" class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="onClickUpdate()">Guardar Cambios</button>
        <button v-else class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="onClickEdit()">Editar</button>

        <button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="onClickDelete()">Eliminar</button>
    </div>
```

y mi controlador de update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $pensamiento = Pensamiento::find($id);
    $pensamiento->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
    $pensamiento->save();
    return $pensamiento;
}
```

a la hora de hacer edit y delete me sale este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código que muestras en methods, es del componente `PensamientoComponent` o de un hijo de éste? ¿Tienes un `$this` en Vue? (porque debiera ser simplemente `this`). Tienes alguna arrow function? Respecto al error 500, tienes que mirar los logs de php

Comment: Gracias por responder :) 
el problema es por el componente PensamientoComponent el cual es hijo y su componente padre es MisPensamientosComponent. no subi el componente padre porque el actualizar y eliminar que tiene el hijo es el que se conecta con mi controlador en laravel

Comment: según lo que anduve leyendo, el error 500 se debe a un problema con el servidor y la verdad que cuando dejo de hacer return $pensamiento en mi controlador sale otro error 404. pero según el curso que vi necesita hacer return para traer los datos actualizados

Comment: Los strings que le pasas a axios los tienes con backticks verdad? o sea **`** en vez de **'** ?

Comment: (tuve que poner esto en otro comentario para evitar el reemplazo de los backticks) Podrías probar convirtiendo las promesas en await ej: `await axios.delete(` ` `/pensamientos/${this.pensamiento.id}` ` `);
this.$emit('delete');`